# rollback all the queries if any query returns an error in mysql database

Tags: mysql

i have two tables like
SAMPLETABLE1 (CNT INT(5));
SAMPLETABLE2 (CNT INT(5));

i have a stored procedure as follows :

```
create procedure p1()
begin
declare k int;
DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
 BEGIN
  SET k = 0;
  ROLLBACK;
 END;

set autocommit = off;
START TRANSACTION;
update sampletable2 set cnt = cnt + 5; 
insert into sampletable1 values ('5s');   
 IF k < 1 
    THEN
      ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
      COMMIT;
    END IF;
end;
//
```

when i run this procedure it returns error "Data truncated for column 'cnt' at row 1" and first update is fired which is okay i know i am insert a character value into a number datatype.

i want my first query to be rollback if any of query return exception but it is not happening please suggest.

Comment: An exit handler is invoked as soon as the for sqlexception is encountered, statements after the statement which caused the error are not executed and the statements between the begin and end statement immediately after the declaration are executed and the procedure terminates. Therefore you don't need the if k  < 1 code block - you can simply replace this with a commit statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Create table/insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE sampletable1
    (`CNT` INT(5))
;

INSERT INTO sampletable1
    (`CNT`)
VALUES
    (1)
;

CREATE TABLE sampletable2
    (`CNT` INT(5))
;

INSERT INTO sampletable2
    (`CNT`)
VALUES
    (1)
;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM sampletable1
```

**Result**

```
   CNT  
--------
       1
```

**Stored procedure**

Ive worked here with `CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION`

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE p1()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE doRollback BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET doRollback = 1;

    SET autocommit = off;     
    START TRANSACTION; 
    UPDATE sampletable2 SET CNT = CNT + 5;
    INSERT INTO sampletable1 (CNT) VALUES ('5s');   

    IF doRollback THEN
      ROLLBACK;
    ELSE 
      COMMIT;
    END IF;        
  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Call p1()**

```
CALL p1();
```

**Result**

```
1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: CALL p1()

Error Code: 1265
Data truncated for column 'CNT' at row 1

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.002 sec
```

**Check sample1 table**

```
SELECT * FROM sampletable1
```

**Result**

```
   CNT  
--------
       1
```